# how can i disable save button in ckeditor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I don't want any ajax functionality currently in ckeditor. How can i remove that button from toolbar? If i do not disable that save button i get strange errors when i click that button. I followed this tutorial :-

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your config file, you can specify your own toolbar (and leave out the save button).

For example, my config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';

    config.uiColor = '#F6F6F6';
    config.fontSize_sizes = '8/8px;9/9px;10/10px;11/11px;12/12px;14/14px;15/15px;16/16px;18/18px;20/20px;22/22px;24/24px;26/26px;28/28px;36/36px;48/48px;72/72px' ;
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
    config.format_tags = 'p;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;div'
    config.height = "400px";
    // config.protectedSource.push( //g ); // Allows PHP Code
    // config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.skin = 'kama';
    config.undoStackSize = 90;
    config.width = "98%";

    config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
    config.scayt_autoStartup = false;

    config.toolbarCanCollapse = false;
    config.toolbar = 'Cms';
    config.toolbar_Cms =
    [
        ['Source'],
        ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord'],
        ['Undo','Redo','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
        '/',
        ['Bold','Italic','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
        ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
        ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
        ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
        ['Image','Table','SpecialChar'],
        '/',
        ['Styles','Format','FontSize'],
        ['TextColor'],
        ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']
    ];
};
```

Comment: Thanks i will go with your config only :). It's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to omit it from the [toolbar array](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar)...

```
config.toolbar_Basic =
[
    ['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink','-','About']
];
```

see how Save is gone in the above example?

```
config.toolbar_Basic =
[
    ['Save', 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink','-','About']
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add in my own findings here for v4.x as I wanted a way to disable a button on an 'as needed' basis without loading in the config.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editorID'];
if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editorID' , {
  removeButtons: 'btnName',
});
```