# Cannot remove save button from ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and i have my own independent save mechanism outide of ckeditor, so i would like to remove the save button from my toolbar.

I have tried many different ways to remove it.

My most recent attempt:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace(div, {    
        uiColor: '#1b3075',
        removeButtons: 'Save',
        removePlugins: 'Save'
    });
```

If i stick any other button name in place of 'save' then the button is removed but the save button is never removed.

Any help here appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling save button enabled/disabled state programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026122/controlling-save-button-enabled-disabled-state-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305929/how-can-i-disable-save-button-in-ckeditor

Comment: I've viewed both of those pages previously and those answers didn't solve my problem, hence the new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing 'Save' with the following

```
removeButtons: 'About',
removePlugins: 'About',
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: Can you please give me the javascript source for it ?

Comment: In current version of CKEditor (4.10) this does not remove the SAVE button, only the ABOUT button.  The original code of the OP now does seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the following line in config.js

`config.removePlugins = 'save';`

im using ckeditor4

Answer (score 0):

if it still don't work you can use CSS to hide un-necessary buttons, something like:

```css
.cke_button__save, 
.cke_button__newpage, 
.cke_button__preview, 
.cke_button__print, 
.cke_button__templates{
  display: none;
}
```